# Error moving VLC to 22.04 desktop

Tags: 22.04, vlc, .desktop

I just updated to Ubuntu 22.04. I installed VLC and want a shortcut on my desktop. When trying to drag it from Files to Desktop, I got the error message that moving it into /home/frank/Desktop from /snap/bin/vlc has permission denied. Any ideas?

Comment: snap has very tight security restrictions. Which desktop environment are you using (gnome, unity, ... )?

Comment: The About page shows Gnome 42.5.

Comment: Okay, now I understood what you tried. Of course you can not *move* something from `/snap/bin`, because move means copy+delete and you can not delete from `/snap` (owned by root). Howerver, the default Ubuntu Gnome has a "Favorite Bar". Use the dot icon (lower left) and search for "vlc". Right-mouseclick let you add the icon to the "Favorite".

Comment: I just found a gnome-extension to put icons on desktop: https://github.com/Tommimon/add-to-desktop

Comment: @Marco That link led me to a lot of confusing information, but I eventually got VLC on my desktop. I'm still not sure what of Tweaks, Gnome Shell, Gnome Shell  Integration, Gnome Shell Manager, and more I have installed, or installed and enabled. I can't find a lot of what I thought I put on the computer. The Gnome Desktop Environment doesn't make it easy for inexperienced users to use it. However, I can now open VLC from the desktop, but I think I'll take a rest before trying to use that extension on other apps. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Usually the "unexperienced" user just use it as it is, in the dock (favorite-bar). I did not ask, why you need it on the desktop.

Comment: I have the dock on the left side of my 14" laptop, to leave more vertical space for reading. There's a limited number of icons that can be always showing there. Using the desktop as well, I won't ever have to worry about prioritising which ones to show.